# ESLint exhaustive-deps: ignore value that came from a ref

Tags: reactjs, eslint, use-ref

I have a utility function to store an ever-changing value in a ref:

```js
export function useRefOf<T>(value: T) {
  const ref = useRef(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref;
}
```

However, when I use this in an effect that I don't want to re-render on the changing of a value:

```js
const someValueRef = useRefOf(someValue);

useEffect(() => {
  doSomeGreatStuff(someValueRef.current);
}, [doSomeGreatStuff])
```

I break the ESLint `exhaustive-deps` rule:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'someValueRef'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

I know that if I used a regular `useRef` instead of my `useRefOf` though, ESLint wouldn't complain.

How can I tell ESLint to treat `useRefOf` like a ref from `useRef` and tolerate it not being in dependency arrays?

Comment: The same happens if you pass refs through props, or return refs from custom-hooks as you are doing. Eslint has no way to know that that is a React RefObject type, so it complains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Often, with `exhaustive-deps`, the "clean" way to solve the problem without ignoring the rule is to add the value to the dependency array, even if doing so doesn't actually accomplish anything. That approach can be used here. A ref is stable; the value returned by a given component's `useRef` will be the same object every time. So, your code will perform identically to what it's doing now if you change

```
}, [doSomeGreatStuff])
```

to

```
}, [doSomeGreatStuff, someValueRef])
```